# Display a boolean model field in a django form as a radio button rather than the default Checkbox

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

This is how I went about, to display a Boolean model field in the form as Radio buttons Yes and No.

```
choices = ( (1,'Yes'),
            (0,'No'),
          )

class EmailEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    #Display radio buttons instead of checkboxes
    to_send_form = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices,widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
    model = EmailParticipant
    fields = ('to_send_email','to_send_form')

    def clean(self):
    """
    A workaround as the cleaned_data seems to contain u'1' and u'0'. There may be a better way.
    """

    self.cleaned_data['to_send_form'] = int(self.cleaned_data['to_send_form'])
    return self.cleaned_data
```

As you can see in the code above, I need a clean method that converts input string to an integer, which may be unnecessary.

Is there a better and/or djangoic way to do this. If so, how?

And no, using `BooleanField` seems to cause a lot more problems. Using that seemed obvious to me; but it isn't. Why is it so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `TypedChoiceField`.

```
class EmailEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    to_send_form = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                         choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
                    )
```

Comment: note that choices is a sequence of pairs (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField).  Not quite sure what's in the pairs, tho.

Comment: I looked in widgets.py, choices is a list of tuples of the form (choice_value, choice_label).

Comment: When the form is rendered in the HTML with an instance in place, and if the instance has the value of this field as True this example will not render the correct radio button selected. Because the radio button will expect 1 or 0 as the value and this answer will return True or False. Solution is to use a lambda that returns boolean as `coerse` instead of int and use True - False as the choices. Such as `coerce=lambda x: x == 'True'`

Answer (score 6):

```
field = BooleanField(widget=RadioSelect(choices=YES_OR_NO), required=False)


YES_OR_NO = (
    (True, 'Yes'),
    (False, 'No')
)
```

Comment: I think Daniel's solution is better.... I don't think this one will coerce the submitted value back to a bool.

Comment: This answer doesn't state if it should be placed in the model or in the form.
I'm somewhat new to django forms and I would like to see if this would work and where would it work?

Comment: @StevenRogers this a form field not a model field; so it represents one field within a django form, where multiple fields compose a single form. Model fields on the other hand represent the columns of a database table.

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you want the horizontal renderer.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1956/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deal with boolean values instead of integer values then this is the way to do it.

```
forms.TypedChoiceField(
    choices=((True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')),
    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
    coerce=lambda x: x == 'True'
)
```