# Specify choices in model and RadioButton in ModelForm renders not selected value "------"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My goal is to be able to use get_FOO_display(), and so as far as I understand I will have to have choices specified in the model field. At the same time I am wanting to render the form using a ModelForm as a RadioButton.

The problem I am having is that the default value of "------" that would be used in a dropdown select is showing up as one of my RadioButton options.

**models.py**

```
class Medication(models.Model):
    YESNO_CHOICES = [(0, 'No'), (1, 'Yes')]
    Allergies = models.BigIntegerField(verbose_name='Allergies:', choices=YESNO_CHOICES)
```

**forms.py**

I have tried just specifying a RadioButton widget in the ModelForm.

```
class mfMedication(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Medication
        widgets = {
        'Allergies': RadioSelect(),
        }
```

and also specifying the RadioButton with the CHOICES.

```
class mfMedication(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Medication
        widgets = {
        'Allergies': RadioSelect(choices=Medication.YESNO_CHOICES),
        }
```

In both cases I get three radiobuttons:

```
"": -------
0 : No
1 : Yes
```

The only way I do not get the "-------" is to remove choices=YESNO_CHOICES from my model field, but this stops get_FOO_display() from working.

Any approach that you have used to get this working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks. JD.

Comment: Why dont you use `BooleanField` for `Allergies`?

Comment: Apparently I wasn't thinking outside the box - I hadn't used Booleans for anything but checkboxes. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to prevent displaying of `-------` choice, you should specify [`empty_label=None`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label) in your form field.

Also, I recomend you to use [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) for model and [TypedChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#typedchoicefield) for form:

**models.py:**

```
class Medication(models.Model):
    Allergies = models.BooleanField('Allergies:')
```

**forms.py:**

```
class MedicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    YESNO_CHOICES = ((0, 'No'), (1, 'Yes'))
    Allergies = forms.TypedChoiceField(
                     choices=YESNO_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
                )
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. With a slight modification it does everything I need. I just had to keep choices specified in the model as well to allow get_Allergies_display to work. But more importantly I am trying to understand the very different approach than things I had previously thought of. Was the use of Boolean because it was a 0/1 choice, and if I wanted to allow Null would I just go to NullBoolean and the same approach? Secondly, how does coerce come into play I have never used it before? and was that what made you chose TypedChoiceField vs. a ChoiceField? Thanks again!

Comment: Boolean is more logical for yes/no value. And yes: NullBooleanField is for yes/no/i_dont_know. I think, empty_label will serve for null value representation. About TypedChoiceField - I first heard about it today =) I just saw [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033478/display-a-boolean-model-field-in-a-django-form-as-a-radio-button-rather-than-the) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Using the BigIntegerField, you can also set the default=0 or whatever choice you would like it to be.